# Universal Object and Preorder Category

Tags: category-theory

Here is a problem I am working on:

> (a) Suppose that $\mathscr{C}$ is a locally small category and that $\{C_j\mid j\in J\}$ is an indexed set of objects in $\mathscr{C}$. Consider some $A\in\mathscr{C}$ that represents the functor $\prod\limits_{j\in J}\mathscr{C}(C_j,-):\mathscr{C}\to \mathbf{Set}$. What kind of universal object is A? 
> (b) If $\mathscr{C}$ is a small category such that every indexed set of objects $\{C_i\mid i\in I\}$ has a coproduct, then it is a preorder category.

I am not entirely sure what (a) is asking for though... I felt like $A$ is the product of the hom functors, and the universal property holds when considering the functors? As for the second one, I don't really have a clue for now: I tried to show the equalizers of parallel morphisms have something to do with the product of those objects, but I haven't made much progress. Am I supposed to show that it is a preorder category directly? I really appreciate your help!

Comment: (b) is not a complete sentence. “such that every indexed set of objects”.. and there is something missing there, because it doesn’t tell you what happens to every indexed set of objects. There’s a clause missing.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin My apologies! Just edited the question

Comment: Your question is not really about “indexed sets in categories”… see if you can come up with a better subject line. I don’t have time right now, but I’ll come back later if it hasn’t been answered yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (a), let's go back and recall what it means for an object $A$ to represent a functor $F$. We say $A$ represents $F$ if and only if for every object $X$, there is a bijection $a_X\colon F(X)\to \mathscr{C}(A,X)$, and this bijection is functorial, so that if $f\colon X\to Y$ is a morphism in $\mathscr{C}$, then
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
F(X)@>>>\mathscr{C}(A,X)\\
@VF(f)VV@VV\mathscr{C}(A,f)V\\
F(Y)@>>>\mathscr{C}(A,Y)
\end{CD}$$
commutes.

So here we would have that for every object $X$, we have a bijection
$$\prod_{j\in J}\mathscr{C}(C_j,X)\to\mathscr{C}(A,X)$$
which is functorial. What does this bijection tell you? It says that every family of morphisms $f_j\colon C_j\to X$ corresponds to a unique morphism $A\to X$.

Is there a "known" universal object in $\mathscr{C}$ with the property that morphisms from it correspond to families of morphisms from the objects $\{C_j\}$?

For (b), recall that a category is a preorder category if there is at most one morphism between any object $X$ and any object $Y$. So you want to use the fact that every family has a coproduct to show that there is at most one morphism between any two objects. Since there are categories in which every family of objects has a coproduct but that are not preorders (for example, $\mathbf{Group}$), the fact that $\mathscr{C}$ is small must play an important role: the fact that there is a small set of objects and a small set of morphisms will necessarily play an key role.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to MSE!

For (a), they want you to describe the universal property of $A$, and (probably) to specify if it has a more common name (equalizer, pushout, product, initial object, etc.).

If $A$ represents the functor $\prod \mathscr{C}(C_j,-)$, then we have $\mathscr{C}(A,-) \cong \prod \mathscr{C}(A,-)$. That is, a hom out of $A$ is the same information as a hom out of each $C_j$. Does an object with this property have a more common name?

As for (b), we can modify a famous proof of Freyd that [complete small categories are preorders](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/complete+small+category).

Towards a contradiction, say we have two arrows $x \rightrightarrows y$.
Then there are $4$ arrows $x+x \to y$, $8$ arrows $x+x+x \to y$, $16$ arrows $x+x+x+x \to y$, etc.
This feels like a problem, but it's not immediately clear how to make it a problem.

Here's the trick: Since $\mathscr{C}$ is small, it has only a set of morphisms. Say it has $\kappa$ many. But since $\mathscr{C}$ has all coproducts, it has an object $\sum_\kappa x$ where we've summed up $\kappa$ many copies of $x$. It's easy to see (by basically the same argument from before) that there are $2^\kappa$ many arrows $\sum_\kappa x \to y$. So $\mathscr{C}$ must have at least $2^\kappa > \kappa$ many morphisms in it.... But $\kappa$ was supposed to be the total number of morhpisms in $\mathscr{C}$!

---

I hope this helps ^_^